# Android popup window не работает setOnKeyListener при выборе с помощью dPad

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы в popup window обрабатывались нажатия от блютус пульта. Если нажать на поле ввода через сенсорный экран то нажатия на пульте обрабатываются. Если выбрать пультом - то не обрабатываются. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Вот пример кода:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PopupWindow pwindow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void showCustomKeyboard(View view) {
        try {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridlayout, null);
            pwindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
            pwindow.getContentView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            pwindow.getContentView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                            event.startTracking();
                            Button btnBack = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                btnBack.setPressed(true);
                                btnBack.invalidate();
                            } else {
                                btnBack.performClick();
                                btnBack.setPressed(false);
                                btnBack.invalidate();
                            }
                            return true;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                            event.startTracking();
                            Button btnMenu = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
                            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                btnMenu.setPressed(true);
                                btnMenu.invalidate();
                            } else {
                                btnMenu.performClick();
                                btnMenu.setPressed(false);
                                btnMenu.invalidate();
                            }
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });


            pwindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void btnPress(View view) { //onClick Buttons
        if (pwindow != null && pwindow.isShowing()) {
            pwindow.dismiss();
            pwindow = null;
        }
    }

    public void keyboard(View view) { //onClick editText
        showCustomKeyboard(view);
    }
}
```